# RuntimeError: Input type (long int) and bias type (float) should be the same

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, fast-ai

My use case is to produce more images given the dataloader using GAN in fastai. Following is my code.

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
from fastai.vision.gan import *

# Define the generator and critic models
generator = basic_generator(64, n_channels=3, n_extra_layers=1)
critic    = basic_critic   (64, n_channels=3, n_extra_layers=1, act_cls=partial(nn.LeakyReLU, negative_slope=0.2))
dls = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(path, valid_pct=0.2, bs=64, item_tfms=Resize(128), device=device)
learn = GANLearner.wgan(dls, generator, critic, opt_func=partial(Adam, mom=0.))
learn.fit(1, 2e-4)
```

I am getting following error.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f782c65fddec> in <cell line: 3>()
  1 # Train the GAN model
  2 learn = GANLearner.wgan(dls, generator, critic, opt_func=partial(Adam, mom=0.))
----> 3 learn.fit(1, 2e-4)

19 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
457                             weight, bias, self.stride,
458                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
460                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
461 

RuntimeError: Input type (long int) and bias type (float) should be the same
```